# How much is sixty billion double dollars worth?

Tags: trigun

In Trigun, Vash the Stampede is wanted for sixty billion double dollars ($$60,000,000,000).  I don't remember any indication of how much money that actually is in the Trigun universe.  I'm sure it's quite a lot, but how much is it really? Enough to buy a house?  A power plant?  An entire city?

[image: Vash the Stampede's wanted poster]

So, **how much is $$60,000,000,000 actually worth?**

Comment: Do you mean how much is $$60,000,000,000 actually worth?

Comment: Thanks for your addition, I don't think that we need the [tag:currency] tag. For the same reasons we no longer have the [tag:characters] or [tag:character-abilities]. Think this, can there be an expert in "Anime currencies"? You're welcome to join us an discuss it in [chat], or if you want, in [meta].

Comment: Obviously, `$60,000,00,000.00` is a variable that contains the variable with actual amount. You are extracting the value of it by prepending another `$`. this is a variable variable... sorry, I'm from stackoverflow, so this was a joke :P

Comment: I had always assumed a double dollar was one backed with gold, making those dollars worth a lot more than other currencies

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, in one episode, he buys a bag of donuts, about 10-15 of them, and pays $$30. The average donut costs $1.20 (I literally just looked it up on Google [[here]](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_does_the_average_donut_cost?#slide=1)). If you round it to 10 donuts, it's $12. If you round to 15, it's $18. You can safely say that one double dollar is approximately equal to fifty cents ($$1 = $0.50) which, whether on purpose or a total lucky mistake by the author of Trigun, makes a lot of sense, in a weird reverse way. So, by this (way too complicated) logic, he is worth $30,000,000,000.00!

Comment: I know I accepted the other answer almost a year ago, but I love your answer!  Much more specific!  I'm switching my accept to this one.

Comment: @アズーサ Your edit obscured the distinction between dollars and double dollars. Also, the changes in wording did not really help (nor did they do any harm), so I rolled it back.

Comment: @senshin- Sorry, I was not aware of that. :)

Comment: Also I thought it was a typo too.

Answer (score 14):

The one indicator I know of (from the anime) is that that one city was able to use the bounty from the Nebraska family, which was in the neighborhood of $$600,000, to fix their plant, and that was more money than anyone in the city collectively had at their disposal.

Judging from that, the bounty was probably enough to buy multiple cities, and was in all likelihood impossible for the authorities to actually pay

The bounty was intended to be a larger-than-life number, and it would have been an impossibly high amount of money in that universe.

Answer (score -1):

I did the math. According to Google, an average donut is 0.99 dollars. I am going to use the amount of donuts that another person who answered above that Vash bought for $$30. He said 10-15 but for some reason he didn't go for the average of 12 so using that you can find out that $1 is worth $$2.50. If you divide our $$60000000000 by 2.50 to get the amount of real world currency, it is $25000000000.